# Using FindAll on a List<List<T>> type

Tags: c#, .net, list, findall

Assuming

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int ID {get; set; }
   public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

and

```
List<MyClass> classList = //populate with MyClass instances of various IDs
```

I can do

```
List<MyClass> result = classList.FindAll(class => class.ID == 123);
```

and that will give me a list of just classes with ID = 123. Works great, looks elegant.

Now, if I had

```
List<List<MyClass>> listOfClassLists = //populate with Lists of MyClass instances
```

How do I get a filtered list where the lists themselves are filtered. I tried

```
List<List<MyClass>> result = listOfClassLists.FindAll
                      (list => list.FindAll(class => class.ID == 123).Count > 0);
```

it looks elegant, but doesn't work. It only includes Lists of classes where at least one class has an ID of 123, but it includes ALL MyClass instances in that list, not just the ones that match.

I ended up having to do

```
List<List<MyClass>> result = Results(listOfClassLists, 123);

private List<List<MyClass>> Results(List<List<MyClass>> myListOfLists, int id)
{
   List<List<MyClass>> results = new List<List<MyClass>>();
   foreach (List<MyClass> myClassList in myListOfLists)
   {
      List<MyClass> subList = myClassList.FindAll(myClass => myClass.ID == id);
      if (subList.Count > 0)
         results.Add(subList);
   }
   return results;
}
```

which gets the job done, but isn't that elegant. Just looking for better ways to do a FindAll on a List of Lists.
Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep a list of lists, you could do something like this example:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass() { ID = 123, Name = "Apple" };
MyClass b = new MyClass() { ID = 456, Name = "Banana" };
MyClass c = new MyClass() { ID = 789, Name = "Cherry" };
MyClass d = new MyClass() { ID = 123, Name = "Alpha" };
MyClass e = new MyClass() { ID = 456, Name = "Bravo" };

List<List<MyClass>> lists = new List<List<MyClass>>()
{
    new List<MyClass>() { a, b, c },
    new List<MyClass>() { d, e },
    new List<MyClass>() { b, c, e}
};

var query = lists
            .Select(list => list.Where(item => item.ID == 123).ToList())
            .Where(list => list.Count > 0).ToList();
```

query would be `List<List<MyClass>>` holding lists of MyClass objects that passed the test. At first glance, it looks out of order with the Where extension coming after the Select, but the transformation of the inner lists needs to occur first, and that's what's happening in the Select extension. Then it is filtered by the Where.

Comment: this isn't bad. But where would I put the .Count > 0 check to remove List<int> lists that have no matching items?

Comment: Good catch, I just noticed that in the question a moment ago. I'll update the example to match your scenario.

Comment: this works great. Thanks. I'll toss all the ideas to my developer, but I like this one.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>listOfClasses.SelectMany(x=>x).FindAll( /* yadda */)</strike>

Sorry about that, FindAll is a method of List<T>.

This

```
var result = from x in listOfClasses from y in x where SomeCondition(y) select y;
```

or

```
var result = listOfClasses.SelectMany(x=>x).Where(x=>SomeCondition(x));
```

Comment: the 'from x yadda..' answer sort of works. It flattens out the results (mine maintains the List of List data type) but that may not be a bad thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with this

```
List<List<string>> stuff = new List<List<string>>();

List<List<string>> results = new List<List<string>>();

stuff.ForEach(list=> {var result = list.FindAll(i => i == "fun").ToList();
        if (result.Count > 0) results.Add(result);
    });

List<string> flatResult = new List<string>();

stuff.ForEach(List => flatResult.AddRange(List.FindAll(i => i == "fun")));
```

That way you can go with a jagged array or flatten it out.. But the Linq way works well too :-).

Answer (score 0):

While producing a flat `List<MyClass>` will answer your need most of the time, the *exact* answer to your question is:

```
var result = (from list in ListOfClassLists
                          let listWithTheId=
                              (
                               (from myClass in list
                                where myClass.ID == id
                                select myClass)
                                .ToList()
                              )
                          where listWithTheId.Count > 0
                          select listWithTheId
             ).ToList();
```

This code snippet was taken from my Proof of Concept:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ListOfListSelectionSpike
{
    public class ListSpikeClass
    {
        public List<List<MyClass>> ListOfClassLists { get; set; }

        private List<MyClass> list1, list2, list3;

        public ListSpikeClass()
        {
            var myClassWithId123 = new MyClass("123");
            var myClassWithIs345 = new MyClass("456");
            list1 = new List<MyClass> { myClassWithId123, myClassWithIs345 };
            list2 = new List<MyClass> { myClassWithId123, myClassWithIs345, myClassWithId123 };
            list3 = new List<MyClass> { myClassWithIs345, myClassWithIs345 };
            ListOfClassLists = new List<List<MyClass>> { list1, list2, list3 };
        }

        public List<List<MyClass>> GetListOfListsById(string id)
        {
            var result = (from list in ListOfClassLists
                          let listWithTheId =
                              ((from myClass in list
                                where myClass.ID == id
                                select myClass)
                                .ToList())
                          where listWithTheId.Count > 0
                          select listWithTheId)
                          .ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(string id)
        {
            ID = id;
            Name = "My ID=" + id;
        }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to Anthony's solution but using the SQL syntax rather than a 'dot' syntax right? I see both styles used when folks give solutions to questions on stackoverflow, is it just a matter of style preference? I've yet to see where one style has a performance advantage or 'future proof' advantage.

Thanks for your work, it certainly gives me more education.

Comment: yes it is similar to Anthony's solution. Usually I find the LINQ notation more readable, but in this case Anthpny's solution is neat and concise.